# Joining two IQueryable variables of different types together using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The columns names and types are identical, however it's coming from two separate entities. Here is a simplified example:

```
--Query View
var v_res = from s in db.V_CMUCUSTOMER
           select s;

--Values from table less values from view
var res = from s in db.CMUCUSTOMERs
          where !(from v in v_res
            select v.ID).Contains(s.ID)
         select s;

--join table and view values into one variable
var res_v_res = (from c in res
            select c).Union(from v in v_res
            select v);
```

I get the following error however:

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to  System.Linq.ParallelQuery

Comment: I bet if you stopped using 'var', the answer would be clear.  By letting the compiler choose the type of v_res and res, you get to live with its choices.

Comment: The compiler may choose an unexpected type for one of those variables, then it may choose between different implementations of Union based on that choice (System.Linq.Enumerable.Union , System.Linq.Queryable.Union to name two of the possibilities).  Instead, if you specify the type, the compiler will tell you when you ask for the impossible.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you invoke the `Union` method explicitly, i.e. `Enumerable.Union(from c in res select c, from v in v_res select v)`?

Comment: I get the following: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.

Comment: Where are you making the call to `AsParallel()`?  `ParallelQuery` is a result of using that, but I don't see it in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a new anonymous type and use ToList() for both then you should be able to Union them as follows :

```
var v_res = (from s in db.V_CMUCUSTOMER
            select new { custName = s.customer_name custAddress = s.address}).ToList();

--Values from table less values from view
var res = (from s in db.CMUCUSTOMERs
          where !(from v in v_res
            select v.ID).Contains(s.ID)
          select new { custName = s.customer_name custAddress = s.address }).ToList();

--join table and view values into one variable
var res_v_res = v_res.Union(res);
```

This may be onerous if there are dozens of columns but should still work.

Answer (score 0):

When I run a similar query in LINQPad, I get an error message claiming that `s` in `Contains(s.ID)` is not defined in this context.

If I replace `&&` with `where` all queries are successfully executed.